# Is it possible to set the default branch in sonar during the analyzis?

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab-ci, sonarqube-scan

We have many old projects with a master default branch, but the new ones are using main. For now, we'd like to keep both default branch. Is it possible to tell sonar what is the default branch during the analysis?

We are doing the analysis with maven in GitLab, here is the maven command:

```
mvn --batch-mode --no-transfer-progress -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true -B -Dformats=HTML,JSON \
    -Dsonar.branch.name=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME \
    -Dsonar.dependencyCheck.jsonReportPath=target/dependency-check-report.json \
    -Dsonar.dependencyCheck.htmlReportPath=target/dependency-check-report.html \
    -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=target/site/jacoco/jacoco-unit.xml,target/site/jacoco/jacoco-it.xml \
    compile sonar:sonar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the branch name parameter

```
-Dsonar.branch.name=<your-branch-name>
```

Comment: This is already part of the command, sorry I forgot to replace $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS and $BRANCH_PROPERTIES in the command. This is only telling sonar what is the analyzed branch, and it is not set the default branch in SonarQube.